# Multiple conditions in conditional formula in Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I'm a complete newbie to this. I'm trying to have a column show up based on two other selections in the form. So this is what I have based on one choice (after a LOT of googling):

```
=if([$Travel_x003f_] == 'Travel Required',  && [$Transportation] == 'Fleet Vehicle Needed', 'true', 'false')
```

I need to show the column based on if Travel Required is selected, AND if either 'Fleet Vehicle Needed' OR 'Rental Car' is selected. How do I do that?

Comment: What is the data/column type of both the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this conditional formula:

```
=if([$Travel_x003f_] == 'Travel Required' && ([$Transportation] == 'Fleet Vehicle Needed' || [$Transportation] == 'Rental Car') , 'true', 'false')
```

Make sure you are using correct internal names of your columns. Follow this article to get the internal name of your columns: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Microsoft documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)